# Gradle nebula.test fails to download Gradle distribution

Tags: groovy, gradle, spock, nebula-test

I'm writing my first Gradle plugin.  It's functionally working pretty well, and I have a couple of unit tests working.  I'm now starting to set up integration tests using nebula.test.  After resolving a simple Spock version number mismatch problem (I was loading 1.0, but nebula.test still uses 0.7) I'm now trying to run my first test.  When I run it from Eclipse or from the command line, I see it fail with the following stacktrace:

```
org.gradle.api.GradleException: Build aborted because of an internal error.
at nebula.test.functional.internal.DefaultExecutionResult.rethrowFailure(DefaultExecutionResult.groovy:95)
at nebula.test.IntegrationSpec.runTasksSuccessfully(IntegrationSpec.groovy:234)
at com.att.opnfv.yang.gradle.YangPluginIntegSpec.simple(YangPluginIntegSpec.groovy:14)
Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.3-bin.zip'.
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory$ZippedDistribution$1.call(DistributionFactory.java:128)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory$ZippedDistribution$1.call(DistributionFactory.java:116)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildLauncher.run(DefaultBuildLauncher.java:71)
at nebula.test.functional.internal.toolingapi.BuildLauncherBackedGradleHandle.run(BuildLauncherBackedGradleHandle.groovy:78)
at nebula.test.IntegrationSpec.runTasks(IntegrationSpec.groovy:246)
at nebula.test.IntegrationSpec.runTasksSuccessfully(IntegrationSpec.groovy:232)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:618)
at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:160)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:275)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:371)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1300)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory$ProgressReportingDownload.download(DistributionFactory.java:177)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:59)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:46)
at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:46)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory$ZippedDistribution$1.call(DistributionFactory.java:122)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory$ZippedDistribution$1.call(DistributionFactory.java:116)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I imagine that most people will immediately suggest that I should configure my proxy.  I'm pretty sure I've already done that.  My Gradle build wouldn't work at all if I wasn't able to download artifacts from the internet.  I put the relevant proxy config settings in my "~/.gradle/gradle.properties".  I can also download this zip file in my browser, and I can also get it with "wget" from the same shell I ran the build from.  The result from "wget" is interesting, however.  When I run this, I see that it gets an intermediate "301 Moved Permanently" result, which points to "https://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.3-bin.zip".

Is there some part of this distribution download process that doesn't properly handle 301s, or do I have to configure that somehow?

**Update**:

Here's my build.gradle file:

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }

    apply plugin: 'groovy'
    apply plugin: 'java-gradle-plugin'
    apply plugin: 'maven'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
        maven {
            url "http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.snapshot"
        }
        maven {
            url "http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.release"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.9"
        compile gradleApi()
    }

    sourceCompatibility = 1.7

    group = 'com.att.opnfv.yang'
    version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

    sourceSets {
        integTest {
            groovy.srcDir file("src/integTest/groovy")
            resources.srcDir file("src/integTest/resources")
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        integTestCompile sourceSets.main.output
        integTestCompile configurations.testCompile
        integTestCompile sourceSets.test.output
        integTestRuntime configurations.testRuntime

        testCompile( 'com.netflix.nebula:nebula-test:2.2.0' ) {
            exclude module: 'groovy-all'
        }
    }

    task integTest(type: Test) {
        testClassesDir  = sourceSets.integTest.output.classesDir
        classpath     = sourceSets.integTest.runtimeClasspath
    }

    check.dependsOn -= integTest
```

And here's the first incomplete spec I'm trying to use with nebula test:

```
    import nebula.test.IntegrationSpec
    import nebula.test.functional.ExecutionResult

    class YangPluginIntegSpec extends IntegrationSpec {
        def 'simple'() {
            writeHelloWorld("com.example")
            buildFile << '''
            applyPlugin('yang')
            '''.stripIndent()

            when:
            ExecutionResult result = runTasksSuccessfully('build')

            then:
            println result
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you format the stack trace as code? Is there any more to the stacktrace? How are you using nebula-test? Does it work when not behind a proxy?

Comment: Updated to format entire stacktrace as code, along with providing build.gradle and spec class.  I'll try outside of the proxy today.

Comment: Ok, the proxy is the key. I get past that problem when I run this outside of the proxy.  So, how do I communicate proxy settings to nebula test?